# When calculating the volume of an $n-$ball, why do we use the gaussian integrals?

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, gaussian-integral

I am not sure if this is a duplicate, in case it is, please inform me.

I trie to compute the volume of an $n-$ball. That is the volume of $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. My intuition was to use the spherical coordinates, which is pretty hard of we do it in any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Now, one the classical ways of computing the volume of an $n-$ball is to introduce the gaussian integral. That is considering the function $$f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = exp (-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2) $$ and then computing $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fd\mu$$
But this is pretty odd to me, as despite giving the correct result, I still don't understand why it gives the correct result. How come a function $x \mapsto e^{\frac{-1}{2}x^2} $ give the volume of a unit ball? What am I missing? I am pretty sure this must be due to some lack of understanding of the measure theory or integration theory, so could anyone explain why this integral works?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the following paper https://www-jstor-org.sire.ub.edu/stable/2690797?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: The point is that this function is conveniently integrable in both rectangular coordinates and in spherical coordinates (the product is constant on spheres centered at the origin)

Comment: @AdriánHinojosaCalleja The link you provided appears to be inaccessible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Just go [directly to jstor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690797) and via the university.

Comment: @MichaelBurr the exact reference is                                     
Integration of Radial Functions
John A. Baker
Mathematics Magazine
Vol. 72, No. 5 (Dec., 1999), pp. 392-39